# Python 2.7: faster way to iterate over flow accumulation array

Tags: arrays, performance, python-2.7, numpy, iteration

I found different topics about performance to calculate flow accumulation rasters, of other hydrological outputs. In my case I already have a flow accumulation raster, which has been altered to an array, and a 1D array based on that one, in which the order of the 'cells' has been ranked based on the DEM (high to low).

This is used in a larger model to calculate nutriënt transports (among others: from erosion). Calculated erosion is then 'transported' by use of that 1D array towards river cells. My problem is that this process is tremendously slow, and I would like to know if there are other possibilities to speed this up. The entire calculating time of the larger model is depending on this slow proces.

Background info: everything is written in Python 2.7, performance of the computer itself is not the issue (it's a VPC in a network, all other things I wrote run on the same VPC in an acceptable time). The intention is NOT to use arcpy-modules (anything else is welcome). Currently it's largely based on NumPy for array-calculations (arrays were made from the Original rasters for speed).

The main structure of the slow part of the code is below. My guess the reasin it's so slow, is because of it looping over every cell in the array. It's a large array (approx. 800x1000), clipping is no possibility, lumping to larger grid size would be considered only if nothing else works to speed it up, given the estimate of changes in output (larger error?).

My question is: is there any way to make this process faster in calculation, besides clipping the area or lumping to larger cellsizes? So I can still trace (accumulatice) all the sediment (and nutrient) over the array towards the river cells. If that would be not possible, than I can accept that and work towards one of these two options for performance improvement.

In advance many thanks for your time and considerations.

Kind regards,

Rob

```
for ii in range (rows.size-1,-1,-1):           
    rowNr=rows[ii] # retrieve row number of grid ll
    colNr=cols[ii] # retrieve column number of grid cell
        if(Riverheads[rowNr,colNr]==9999.):    
        # Transport sediment(kg cell-1) and nutrients (gr cell-1) to neigbour cells
        # to west cell
            if colNr-1>=0:
            #add inflow + nutrient loads from westcell
        # to east cell
            if colNr+1 <=cols.max():
            #add inflow + nutrient loads from eastcell
        # to south cell
            if rowNr+1<=rows.max():
            #add inflow + nutrient loads from southcell
        # to north cell
            if rowNr-1>=0:
            #add inflow + nutrient loads from northcell
```

Comment: Are the lines with `cols.max()` and `rows.max()` in the actual code, or just the example? It's very costly to calculate these values every iteration. Also, are you familiar with "vectorization"? I.e. do operations on complete arrays instead of looping over individual elements.

Comment: Hello, the cols.max() are indeed in the code, I will store those as a constant, thank you for that.
I read about vectorization, but I can't figure that out for this case, since values are calculated for neighbouring cells in cumulation. So I should calculate a value to the left of the current cell (if that is the flow direction) and from that cell that value should be taken cumulatively with it's own value. If you have an idea of how this could work in vectorization, please let me know, that would be really helpful.